# extract date from datetime stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timestamp

Anyone know how to extract the date from a datetime stamp as part of the where clause?

eg.

```
 select *
 from tableA
 where date between '01/08/2009' and '31/08/2009'
```

(Date is a timestamp!)

Many thanks,
Fiona

Comment: Hi Luke, I'm using MS SQL server.
Thanks
Fiona

Comment: +1 to Luke. Very depend on database engine

Comment: which **version** of SQL Server?? 2008 ?? If so: CAST(date AS DATE) - there's a new datatype called `DATE` in SQL Server 2008 which represents just the date portion - no time.

Comment: but as "gbn" mentioned - if you really have a type `TIMESTAMP` then it's really **not** a date/time stamp but an arbitrary binary value

Answer (score 5):

If this is sql server, it's not possible.  The [timestamp data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(SQL.80).aspx)'s name is misleading, as it does not store any date information of any kind.  All it holds is a sequential value that allows you to establish record order (eg, item A was created before item B), and therefore you don't have enough information in that column alone to know on what day the row was created.

Since the link I provided is Sql Server 2000 specific, also check this link for information on SQL Server 2008:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

> **timestamp** is the synonym for the **rowversion** data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use **rowversion** instead of **timestamp** wherever possible.

To build a real timestamp column in Sql Server, use a DateTime (or DateTime2) data type and set it's default value to `getdate()` or `current_timestamp`.

Answer (score 3):

If a real datetime value, not TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION which is binary(8)...

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @MyValue), 0)
```